# Multiple file systems on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I'm trying to put together a BeagleBone Black using Debian on the EMMC, a separate MicroSD card and a flash USB disk (but could ostensibly be platter media on USB).

My question, simply put: are there any special considerations when moving filesystems off of the EMMC (for instance, /var or /home) and onto non-embedded media, or is it the same as doing it on a larger and more "traditional" *nix system?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a user of Raspberry PI, not BBB but I think in this context is the same.
If external storage device is working, i.e. kernel can handle it, there is enough power etc.
then you can use filesystems as on other hardware platforms. Eventually you
should check /boot/config* file if there is support for desired filesystem
in the kernel or modules.

Cheers,

Comment: I will check `/boot/config*` and get back to you. This might be the answer...